# Permanent of a $3 \times 3$ and $4 \times 4$ matrix from determinants

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, algebraic-complexity, permanent

Let $A$ be a $3 \times 3$ or a $4 \times 4$ matrix with entries $a_{ij}$. Can someone provide me a matrix $B$ so that $\operatorname{per}(A) = \det(B)$? What is the smallest explicit $B$ that is known such that $\operatorname{per}(A) = \det(B)$? Any references on this with explicit examples?

Some restrictions could be the following cases:

Case $(1)$ Only linear functionals are allowed as entries of $B$.

Case $(2)$ Non-linear functionals are allowed provided each term has atmost $O(log(n))$ degree (degree is sum of degree of variables) where $n$ is the size of the matrix involved. In our case, upto degree $2$.

Comment: @v s What are the restrictions on $B$? If there are none, then $$B = \begin{pmatrix} \operatorname{per}(A)\end{pmatrix}$$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix with $\det(B) = \operatorname{per}(A)$, but I am guessing that that is not what you had in mind. [Typically one allows](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jyc/papers/per-det.pdf) the entries of $B$ to be affine linear functions of the variables in $A$.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**[EDIT]**

1. For consistency, I switched the notations from $c(n)$ to $dc(n)$.
2. It was asked by [v s](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/5511/v-s) in the comments whether my answer generalize to higher dimensions. It does and gives an upper bound over any field:
   $$dc(n)\le 2^n-1.$$
   See my draft on this: [An Upper Bound for the Permanent versus Determinant Problem](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/bruno.grenet/publis/UpperBound.pdf).

**[/EDIT]**

[A side comment: I think you could edit your previous question instead of creating a new one.]

I have the following answer for you:

$$\operatorname{per}\begin{pmatrix} a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{pmatrix}=
    \det\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & a & d & g & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & i & f & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & c & i \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & c & 0 & f \\
    e & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    h & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}$$

Note that looking for such references about explicit examples, I could'nt find any and thus the example I give you is an example I built.

This question you are asking is commonly called the "Permanent vs Determinant problem". Suppose we are given an $(n\times n)$ matrix $A$, and we want the smallest matrix $B$ such that $\operatorname{per} A=\det B$. Let us denote by $dc(n)$ the dimensions of the smallest such $B$. Here are historical results:

- [Szegö 1913] $dc(n)\ge n+1$
- [von zur Gathen 1986] $dc(n)\ge n\sqrt 2-6\sqrt n$
- [Cai 1990] $dc(n)\ge n\sqrt 2$
- [Mignon & Ressayre 2004] $dc(n)\ge n^2/2$ in characteristic $0$
- [Cai, Chen & Li 2008] $dc(n)\ge n^2/2$ in characteristic $\neq 2$.

This shows that $5\le dc(3)\le 7$ (the upper bound is the matrix given above).

As I am lazy, I just give you one reference where you can find the other ones. It is the most recent paper I cited, by Cai, Chen and Li: [A quadratic lower bound for the permanent and determinant problem over any characteristic $\neq 2$](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jyc/papers/per-det.pdf).

If you read French, you can also have a look to my slides on this subject: [Permanent versus Déterminant](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/bruno.grenet/publis/talk_ejc11.pdf).

Comment: Thankyou very much. I forgot to mention that I was familiar with the linear and quadratic lower bounds. Your example is new to me and ofcourse I will look at your French Slides:)

Comment: One followup question would be what is the motivation behind your example? Does the general structure generalize to larger matrices?

Comment: I really doubt the lower bound of $5$ is achievable.

Comment: I am also very positive that $c(3) = 6$.

Comment: There is no particular motivation: I just wanted to show an example in my slides explaining this problem to a general audience of PhD students in TCS.

Comment: I looked your slide. I am afraid I don't get the circuit bounds but I am familiar with the other results your have mentioned except your example. One question would be is it even known: $dc(n) < n!$?

Comment: If you know an example where $c(n) = dc(n) < n!$ please let me know. $c(n)$ is the notation to your above answer and $dc(n)$ is the notation in your French Slides. I think if one can get better than $n!$ for even a single $n \in Spec({\mathbb{Z}})$, something much better can be done for all $n \in Spec({\mathbb{Z}})$!

Comment: You are right, I used once $c(n)$ and once $dc(n)$, sorry for that! 
For your question, does'nt Ryser's or Glynn's formula answer? Both are formulas of size $O(n2^n)$ for the permanent. Thus, by Valiant's construction, you build a matrix of dimensions $O(n2^n)$ whose determinant equals the permanent of your original matrix. 
In other words, for any $n$, $c(n)\le O(n2^n)$.

Comment: @bruno Thank you. I just thought about it in the shower. May be I am missing something and have to modify my question. Anyways if one had to make a matrix from Ryser/glynns formula, how would one do that? I am interested more in their structures. What makes them special!!

Comment: I mean converting the formula into a determinant version - is it something canonical?

Comment: $O(n2^{n})$ at $n=3$ is $24$. But you just gave an explicit $7$ upper bound;)! (one is asymptotic and the other is just at $3$.... but in any case is your example better than Ryser's?)

Comment: To convert a formula into a determinant, it is a (classical ?) result by Valiant in 1979. We explain this result in our paper in Section 2.1 (cf [http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.3804]).

Comment: For $n=3$, note that there is a constant in O(n2^n) so that 24 is not the right value. Yet I think that my example is better than simply applying Ryser's formula + Valiant's construction. This is quite normal as one can imagine that going from the permanent to a formula and then back to a determinant is not the best way to do. 
I wouldn't say my example is "better than Ryser's" as the goals are not the same. Note also that Glynn'sor Ryser's formulas are not as good as the trivial formula for $n=3$, they beat it asymptotically only.

Comment: @Bruno, I switch the positions of A and B in the second paragraph. Does the modification make sense?

Comment: @Hsien-Chih, you're right!

Comment: I had a new look at J-Y Cai's paper. Theorem 3 gives a better bound: $c(n)\le O(2^n)$.

Comment: @Bruno: excellent answer!

Comment: @Bruno In the example you have, $Per(A) = Det(B)$, is graph of $B$ planar? You dont seem to use planarity. People usually want to have $B$ as a planar matrix and use sign changes to find orientation whose determinant would provide permanent. You don't seem to use that.

Comment: I do not use planarity at all. I think (even though I did not check it carefully) you can find a minor isomorphic to $K_{3,3}$ pretty easily.
There exist widgets sometimes to make a graph planar that could maybe work here.

Comment: @v s A subsequent [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.02205) by Alper, Bogart and Velasco shows that $c(3)=dc(3)=7$.